# Sql join a table if rows exists otherwise switch to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

considering we have the following query :

```
SELECT ca.Uid Numb,
       ag.Code Cd,
       ag.Name agn,
       ca.TypeId tt
FROM dbo.Event ce
    OUTERAPPLY
(SELECT*FROM dbo.Table1 tca WHERE tca.Uid= ce.Cuid) ca
    OUTERAPPLY
(SELECT*FROM dbo.Table2 tct WHERE tct.Uid= ca.TypeId) ct
    OUTERAPPLY
(SELECT*FROM dbo.Table3 ta WHERE ta.Id = ca.AgId) ag
    OUTERAPPLY
(SELECT*FROM dbo.Table4 tsa WHERE tsa.Uid= ce.SId) ser
    OUTERAPPLY
(
    --- if Rows exists in this table take it 
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table5 ttra
    WHERE ttra.ReferenceId = ce.TransactionRef
    --- Otherwise use this table
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table6 ttra
    WHERE ttra.ReferenceId = ce.TransactionRef
) trx
WHERE trx.ApprovalDateTime ISNOTNULL
```

what i want basically on the outer apply to takes a table5 if rows exists in it using the where `ttra.ReferenceId = ce.TransactionRef`
else use Table6 using the same condition

Comment: What is `OUTERAPPLY`? BTW try `SELECT COALESCE(t1.field, t2.field, etc) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 etc`...

Comment: It is not possible to "Sql join a table if rows exists otherwise switch to another table", the only thing you can do join your tables and handle with a Case When structure the results. Sql is not a programming language and its logic is distinct.

Comment: Can you simplify the problem?  I don't exactly see what the code has to do with the question in the title.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you suffer from *missing spaces*, so I inserted them.

From the way OUTER APPLY is used, it is better (more readable) to use LEFT JOIN. OUTER APPLY is useful if the right part needs to be evaluated for every left-row-value separately, which in the first 4 joins does not seem to be the case.
I'm not sure about the Table5+Table6 join, so I left it in there; but maybe it can also be converted to a LEFT JOIN.

Furthermore I used UNION + NOT EXISTS to join the rows from Table5 with rows from Table6-if-Table5-gives-no-results.

Resulting code:

```
SELECT ca.Uid    Numb,
       ag.Code   Cd,
       ag.Name   agn,
       ca.TypeId tt
FROM      dbo.Event  ce
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 ca ON ca.Uid = ce.Cuid
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 ct ON ct.Uid = ca.TypeId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table3 ag ON ag.Id  = ca.AgId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table4 se ON se.Uid = ce.SId
OUTER APPLY
(
    --- if Rows exists in this table take it 
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table5 t5
    WHERE t5.ReferenceId = ce.TransactionRef
    UNION
    --- Otherwise use this table
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table6 t6
    WHERE t6.ReferenceId = ce.TransactionRef
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table5 WHERE ReferenceId = ce.TransactionRef)
) trx
WHERE trx.ApprovalDateTime IS NOT NULL
```